# Date regex replacement

Tags: regex

I've learn a lot about regex but here I'm blocking.

There is some strings :

```
6 September 2013
13 Mars 2014
20 Mars 2012
```

I need to transform the first one into : 06 September 2013

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please add the tag for the language you are using!

Comment: You'll need to do a separate format operation to turn `6` into `06`.

Comment: What have you tried and what does it produce? Show us your code so we can tell you what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's always in the beginning of the line, simply replace `/^([0-9] )/` with `0\1` (switch `\1` out with whatever is the capture group reference in your regex language).

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/rN1nR9)